# SocketIO(app) missing required positional argument 'mode'

Tags: python, flask, flask-socketio

I'm trying to get the simple example of Flask-SocketIO working, but I'm getting an error saying I'm missing a required positional argument 'mode', even though the documentation / official example don't show such a parameter:

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After a lot of head-scratching, I realized it was happening because I accidentally imported the wrong SocketIO with my IDE: I imported `socket.SocketIO` instead of `flask_socketio.SocketIO`.  When I fixed the import statement the error went away.